# Script automation upload files from PC (Windows) to Linux server then rename them

Tags: bash, powershell, batch-file, cmd, putty

I would like to automate following manual tasks:

A list of files: `a.csv`, `b.csv`, `c.csv` in a folder named `files`

1. Rename these files to `a_1.csv`, `b_1.csv`, `c_1.csv`
2. Upload these files to a Linux server (may connect via PuTTY with username and password)
3. After finishing upload, rename them back to `a.csv`, `b.csv`, `c.csv`.

What did I try so far:

1. Using batch file to rename and then using PuTTY to upload file. But I'm stuck at renaming files back to the originals. I have no ideas how to store the original names.
2. Using PowerShell but I have no ideas when the upload process finishes.

Could you please give me some ideas to get these tasks done? I did try research a lot but no success.

Comment: Any language will do.  `1` cd to the directory.  `2` get a list of files to process (dir)  `3` loop on the list `4` for each file, 1 by 1, copy the file to the new name.  `5` upload all the copies `6` delete the copies.  The copies could be in a specific directory to avoid messing up your source directory.  `FYI` you could `scp` or `sftp` the files (depends what comes with putty, I do not have it close at hand to check).

Comment: This question is far too broad for this site; you should know that as a long-time member... You already split your task into pieces, please try to solve them on your own; when stuck, come back here and ask specific questions (following [ask] and providing a [mcve]), but one at a time; and you should delete this one...

Comment: agree with above, if you problem is renaming files, then make your Q **just** about that. Show your best attempt to code a solution, and everyone will dive it to fix it for you. Good luck.

Comment: What tool are you actually using to upload the files? PuTTY cannot be used to upload files.

Comment: @aschipfl: Agree but sometime I need some sugestions only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivial to do, if you use a client that supports [masks to modify file name as the file is uploaded](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/operation_mask).

For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/), you can do:

```
put C:\local\path\*.* /remote/path/*_1.csv
```

It will upload all files, storing them with `_1` suffix on the server. And you do not even need to rename the local files.

For a start, see [guide to automating file transfer with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*